# Column sorting using jQuery tablesorter

Tags: jquery-ui, tablesorter

I want to sort a column in table which has data like this "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss S : few more strings". 
This data is string. I am using jquery.tablesorter 2.0 to sort it based on date. I am not able to sort it. Can you please help...

Amy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use one of the [date-extract parsers available here](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/parsers/parser-date-extract.js#L61), and [here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/3884/) of it working:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: "extractYYYYMMDD",
    is: function (s) {
        // don't auto detect this parser
        return false;
    },
    format: function (s, table) {
        var date = s.replace(/\s+/g, " ").replace(/[\-.,]/g, "/").match(/(\d{4}[\/\s]\d{1,2}[\/\s]\d{1,2}(\s+\d{1,2}:\d{2}(:\d{2})?(\s+[AP]M)?)?)/i);
        if (date) {
            date = date[0].replace(/(\d{4})[\/\s](\d{1,2})[\/\s](\d{1,2})/, "$2/$3/$1");
            return $.tablesorter.formatFloat((new Date(date).getTime() || ''), table) || s;
        }
        return s;
    },
    type: "numeric"
});

$('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blackice',
    headers: {
        1: {
            sorter: 'extractYYYYMMDD'
        }
    },
    widgets: ['zebra', 'columns']
});
```

Comment: Hi, awesome... Great guidance.